# npm update unlinks linked packages

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, npm-link

I have a project, which consists of one root node package containing subpackages linked together by **npm link** - these subpackages depend on each other (listed in package.json dependencies) and the structure basically looks like this:

```
-rootpackage
--subpackageA
--subpackageB
```

Lets say subpackageA has dependency on subpackageB, so I link them to avoid publishing/reinstalling subpackageB in subpackageA after every change in the source of subpackageB. 
The link works just fine until I run `npm update` in subpackageA, which causes the subpackageB to be unlinked.

Now, I see two options:

1. I can theoretically run the `npm link` operation after each `npm install` or `npm update` to ensure the links are always present. This works with `postinstall` in case of installation, but in case of an update the `postinstall` is not called. I don't know any **postupdate** command for npm, which is to be called after update.
2. Maybe there is a way to do this more cleverly, perhaps with **yarn**, which I am also using, in a way, that it kind of prevents unlinking or excludes the update for my subpackages, so I don't lose the links between my subpackages, but right now I am not aware of such a way.

Is there any way to make one of those options work or any other way to solve this problem ? I need to keep this and other links so we don't have to run `npm link` after every installation/update. I can't really find information about this issue anywhere. Btw I am using Node 6.4.0 and NPM 3.10.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution is to use [Yarn Workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/) or maybe project like [Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna).

**Yarn Workspaces** is a utility that expects a structure similar to what was described in the question and which maintains the linking subpackages and root automatically. It is very easy to set up (just 2 lines in root *package.json* and executing `yarn` for the first time) and after it you don't have to worry about `upgrade` or `install` at all, the links stay in place unless you delete them manually.

**Lerna** expands on that and provides you with additional tooling for managing multipackage projects. It can use Yarn Workspaces internally for the linking if you use *yarn* but it is not a requirement and works fine with *npm*. Just make sure to have Git because last time I checked Lerna didn't work with SVN or other VCSs.